# How to create JS/TS file in VS Code when missing import

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I sometimes type :

`import something from "./something";`

knowing the file `./something.js` does not exist. Is there a way to tell VS Code to create it ?

Comment: Thanks @Gama11 for removing the extensions tag : I thought maybe an extension existed for that purpose, that's why I had added it in the first place.

Comment: I also miss that from my Eclipse days! any luck ?

Comment: is your question only about relative path imports? because with `paths` in tsconfig, this could get ambiguous easily.